# Wildfly 16 sudden restart| WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name | MODCLUSTER000021

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-16

Wildfly 16 in cluster sudden restarts printing stopped driver service name

```
WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = selskapsdata-1.5-SNAPSHOT.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_19_3
MODCLUSTER000021: All pending requests drained from default-host:/wildfly-services in 0.0 seconds
WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:/datasources/eiMastDS]
Stopped Deployment
etc
```

There is no killing from OOM (No Signal from OS to kill wildfly.
There is no out of memory error.
Node 1 just restart like this and then node2 and node3 get singleton service message and tries to redeploy.

Hostcontrller mentions

```
WFLYHC0027: Unregistering server clusternode01
```

This happen every night at 00:05. I could not see what is actually going on. Can anyone sugggest?

Comment: That seems like very specific timing.  The log lines you're showing are during shutdown - the cause is likely earlier in the file.  Are you sure there isn't something running at 00:05 like a database backup, system backup, or something else?

Comment: @stdunbar: No we have no came across any such activity. Moreover it is one servergroup not all servergroup of wildfly. We have even move some services to other server group (incuding heavy size or heavy memory eating) but issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it by removing Load Metrics.

Some XYZ changed settings to ANY.

So when process or memory extensive application runs; It tried to redeploy it to other nodes.

Then it shows out of memory, classloader exceptions or sudden stop